# Not getting the expected output when using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I was converting react class components to functional components in one of my projects.

This is the class component

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.func1().then((res) => {
      this.func2();
    })

  }
  async func1() {
    this.setState({
      user: "ishan"
    })
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
  }

  func2() {
    console.log("user state: ",this.state.user);
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This gives the following output in the console

```
user state: ishan
```

This is the corresponding functional component

```
export const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    func1().then((res) => {
      func2();
    });
  }, []);

  const func1 = async () => {
    setUser("ishan");
    const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
  };

  const func2 = () => {
    console.log("user state: ",user);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This gives the following output in the console:

```
user state: null
```

I'm not sure why the user state is null in case of functional component, the flow of logic is similar in both the cases. Please explain the difference in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in closures.

Everything inside the `useEffect`s callback will only ever run on mount, hence, `user` will always be `null` there because closures "remembered" only its initial state.

One way to workaround this issue would be to split your `useEffect` into 2:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  func1();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  func2();
}, [user]);
```

In this case, `func2` will run each time `user` changes.

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for answering, but can you please explain in detail why it remembered its initial state in case of useEffect ?

Comment: @IshanVarshney useEffect with an empty array runs once on mount. In the context of the first render pass, `user` is always `null`. At some point after your async call is completed, you call setState. At that point, at the _next render_, `user` will be `ishan`. in that next render (the first time at which point the user variable has a value) you do nothing with the value. Your effect only runs in the context of that first render, where the user is always null.

Answer (score 1):

#### Each render has it's own state, effect, props, and everything else

- according to [this article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-props-and-state) from Dan Abramov's blog

In order to better understand this, we can put a log statement outside `func2` like this:

```
export const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    func1().then((res) => {
      func2();
    });
  }, []);

  const func1 = async () => {
    setUser("ishan");
  };

  const func2 = () => {
    console.log("user state: ",user);
  };
  console.log("user state from outside: ",user); // <- put a log statement outside

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And reload the app, you will get this output:

```
user state from outside: null
user state from outside: null

user state: null
user state: null

user state from outside: ishan 
user state from outside: ishan
```

Both `user state: null` and `user state from outside: null` are expected to have a null value, as the first render has a user state as null, and both log statement are pointing the state at that particular render, but the `outside log statement` has a updated state logged out.

That's because the state gets updated by `func1`, causing component to rerender and thus outside log gets executed, and as opposed to initial render's null value, this render(completely different from the initial render) has an updated value. As useEffect has an empty dependency, it only runs once after initial render, and inside it `func2` won't run this time.

[Check out sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-fast-5pfdlt?file=/src/App.js)